# Absolute values in Riemann integrals

Tags: real-analysis, indefinite-integrals, riemann-integration

I've a doubt regarding definite Riemann integral.

I know that this is true  $\mid \int_a^b f(x) dx\mid \leq \int_a^b \mid f(x) \mid  dx$

And there is a theorem that states that if $f$ is integrable, than $\mid f \mid$ is integrable but the opposite implication is not valid.

I must say that I'm not familiar with the proofs of these facts but I find the two facts quite in contrast with each other.

> If the inequality holds than, thinking about the area under the graph, if $\mid f\mid$ can be integrated, then why $f$ should not be? I mean the inequality states that the area under the graph of $f$ is someway "less" than the one under the graph of  $\mid f\mid$, therefore if I find the area under the graph of  $\mid f\mid$ then I should be able to find the one under the graph of $f$, thus if  $\mid f\mid$ is integrable, $f$ should be too.

Of course I'm missing something, but what? I can't see it.

Thanks in advice for your help

Comment: The problem with your reasoning is in the concept of "area". Mathematically the area is defined in terms of integrals and not the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the function
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}1, \  x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ -1, \ x \ \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}  \end{cases}$$
Now $|f(x)| = 1$ and clearly the constant function is integrable, but $f$ is not Riemann integrable on any interval.

Your intuition about the areas is only a part of the theory of Riemann integration. It is useful to have a toolbox of "pathological" objects (such as the above integral, another example is the Cantor set for other areas of math) to test "intuitive" theorems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Of course it's wrong to think only in terms of areas! Being more specific this doubt raised because if I think to improper integral, then there is the absolute convergence test that uses the inequality in my question. But in that case, what one does is to show that the integral of $\mid f \mid$ converges and from that it follows that the integral of $f$ converges too.So I find strange the theorem in the question because from the behaviour of $f$ deduces the behaviour of $\mid f\mid$ while in improper integral it's exactly the opposite

Comment: The convergence of an improper integral, and the integrability of some function are not related in a strict sense. I suggest finding your favorite (rigorous) analysis textbook, and reading the definitions of both of these things carefully, and think about how they are (and aren't!) related to each other.